# make a switch in a eureka Pushrow to hide a specific row

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I have this function in an eureka form:

```
   +++ Section("DADES COMANDA")

   <<< TableInlineRow<String>("segments"){ row in
    row.title = "PRODUCTE:"
    row.value = ">"
    row.options = ["Persianes", "Mosquiteres"]
    }

    <<< PushRow <String>() {row in
    row.title = "COLOR:"
    row.options = ["BLANC", "MARFIL", "999"]
    row.value = ""
    row.selectorTitle = ""
    row.value = ""

    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Persianes'"
    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'Mosquiteres'"
}
```

how can I put a switch to choose `$0.hidden = "$ segments! = 'Persianes'"` or `$0.hidden = "$ segments! = 'Mosquiteres'"`

Thank you.

Comment: Use a `Condition.function`

Comment: yes, I would like to put a switch, but I do not know how to put the function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$segments` represents an `SegmentedRow<String>` row apply a `Condition.function` this way

```
$0.hidden = Condition.function(["segments"], { form in
     guard let segmentedRow = form.rowBy(tag: "segments") as? SegmentedRow<String>,
         let value = segmentedRow.value else { return false }
     return !["Persianes", "Mosquiteres"].contains(value) 
})
```